# Variable $self in Perl is undefined

Tags: perl, arguments, undefined, self, perl5.8

I am writing a Perl script which makes use of a Perl module, Module.pm.

Module.pm is like so:

```
package Module;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub getInfo {

    my $self = shift;
    #my $var = shift;

    if (!$self)
    {
        my $errmsg = "My ERROR MESSAGE";
        return [1, $errmsg];
    }

    return [1, $self];
}1;
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
use Module

my $result = Module::getInfo();
```

But I keep getting a FATAL ERROR (at Module.pm) undefined object at line #. Why is that?

Furthermore if I remove the first comment in the getInfo() subroutine and add another argument to my calling line then I don't get the same error. Why? I thought I didn't have to send the Module object as an argument to call the subroutine?

This is a Linux server using Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: `Module.pm did not return a true value at script.pl line 3.` — it really helps if you don't introduce new errors when constructing your reduced test case.

Comment: sorry but wouldnt you just need to add a 1; to the end of the module?

Comment: How about a `package` line at the top of Module?

Comment: Do you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a member function of a package, the package name is passed as an implicit first argument only if you use the `->` notation.  This is known as a "method call"; it can also search the class hierarchy to determine what to call. If the prefix is a class name, the implicit first argument is the name of the package, as a string. If the prefix is an object reference, the implicit first argument is that object reference.

With the `::` notation, it's an ordinary subroutine call with no implicit first argument.

For example:

```
% cat foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

package M {
    sub getInfo {
        my($self) = shift;
        say "\$self = ", ($self // 'undef');
    }

    1;
};

M::getInfo();
M->getInfo();
% ./foo.pl
$self = undef
$self = M
%
```

Change `Module::getInfo()` to `Module->getInfo()`.

This is discussed in more detail in the Perl documentation:

- [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) (subroutines)
- [`perldoc perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) (object reference)
- [`perldoc perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) (Object-Oriented Programming in Perl Tutorial)

Older versions of Perl had `perltoot` and `perlboot` tutorials; they've been superseded by `perlootut` as of 5.20 (or possibly earlier).

Comment: Thank you so much I love you it did the trick, I have been stuck on this for too long!

Comment: So what is the difference between calling the Module like '::' and with '->' .

Comment: `->` passes an implicit first argument. `::` doesn't.

Comment: `->` also will invoke inherited methods.

Comment: `Foo()` (or `Bar::Foo()`) is a subroutine call. `$o->Foo()` (or `$o->Bar::Foo()`) is a method call. Method calls are provided with the invocant (the LHS of the `->`) as an argument, and the searching the class heirachy to find the method.

Comment: @ikegami: I've updated the first paragraph. Please check for accuracy and clarity. Thanks.

Comment: The invocant doesn't have to be an object reference for inheritance to kick in.

Comment: @tobyink: Do you have an example?

Comment: @KeithThompson: no objects anywhere here... `perl -E'sub Foo::hello { say "Hello" }; @Bar::ISA = "Foo"; Bar->hello'`